# Order of Execution - Publish After Commit Platform Event when Invoked by Trigger

Tags: trigger, platform-event, assignment-rules, order-of-execution

### Use Case

I need to evaluate records after their assignment rules have been updated, workflows do not meet this requirement because I need complex apex logic after the record has met the condition.

I believe process builders are also not possible as they are executed before assignment rules.

### Question

Assuming the above is correct, I plan on publishing a platform event after commit in a trigger. The platform event would then invoke a process builder to then invoke the apex, but I am unsure as to when a platform event is published when invoked from a trigger.

Given order of execution is:

- Before Flows
- Before Triggers
- Validation Rules
- Duplicate Rules
- After Triggers
- Assignment Rules
- Auto-Response Rules
- Workflow Rules
- If updated via workflow field updates, update and after update triggers ran again.

If I use a publish after commit platform event, will the event be published after the first after triggers or after the workflow rules / second round of after triggers?

The documentation states that after the duplicates rules, but before the first after triggers:

> Saves the record to the database, but doesn't commit yet.

I would assume this means the platform even would wait until the last round of workflow rules/after triggers to be published, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process Builder runs *after* assignment rules. If you need complex logic, you could set up a Process Builder that calls an InvocableMethod (Apex) that can then perform your complicated evaluation logic. You can also build this as a Flow triggered from Process Builder. There's no need to go asynchronous with this unless you're already bumping up against governor limits.

Comment: Thanks. In the order of execution, process builder is not explicitly listed, does it fall under the "workflow rules" step?

Comment: @S.B. It's step 14, immediately after workflow rules. Process Builder is the builder, the thing that runs is the "process."